# Should I call fopen - fclose every fwrite action

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, file-handling, fclose

I am making something similar to `commit log` in database system. The system is able to handle ~ 20,000 events / sec. Each event occupies ~16 bytes. Roughly, the system will write to `commit log` at a speed of ~312.5 kB / sec. Each `commit log` file will contain at most of 500,000 events.

I have a question that: Should I call `fopen - fwrite - fclose` for each event, OR should I call `fopen` once when creating a new file, then a series of `fwrite` and finally `fclose`?

Comment: `fopen, fclose` are expensive so not recommended for each write. However, to be crash consistent, you may want to flush the file periodically.

Comment: @user3386109 Unfortunately there is no standard way to "prevent you from losing more than 1 event on abnormal termination". If the power is cut, for example, then whatever data the drive controller has buffered yet not written to platter will be lost. There is no standard way to force the drive controller to write the contents of its buffer to the platter. `fflush` doesn't deal with that. `fflush` deals with forcing the OS to send unwritten data to the drive controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, it might be even better to revert to *open/write/close* and get rid of C buffered output completely. Log files are typically consisting of a high volume of nearly identical (size-wise) writes and do not really gain much from C buffering. Low level, unbuffered I/O would also relieve you of calling fflush() and can guarantee to write every single log entry as atomic entity.

Given the volume you mentioned, you should probably *still* not close and re-open the file between writes.

Comment: I am checking low-level file IO APIs on Windows. It seems that I still have to call _commit to force a flush to disk. Is there the equivalent thing on Posix?

Comment: The POSIX equivalent to *_commit()* would probably be *fsync()*. And I would probably use neither. It depends a bit in *what* you are logging. If your logfile is intended for post-mortem-analysis or recovery of a computer application, it probably makes sense to have a as much as possible log entries secured. If you're logging some *external* events, though, I would not go that route.

Answer (score 2):

**fopen/fwrite/fclose** 20k times per second looks pretty expensive.
Consider calling **fflush** as an alternative.

If you are looking to use it in order to record database transactions for possible recovery, you may need to rethink it.   The f family of functions use buffering so in the event of a crash the final buffer may or may not have actually made it to disk.

Comment: Yes. I intend to use `commit logs` for recovery purpose. Could you please give me suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: Use a database with transactional support.

Answer (score 0):

You're not obliged to, no... and in fact it would be a much better idea to call `fflush` as suggested by [EvilTeach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002721/1989425).

However, better yet, if you can avoid calling `fflush` that would be ideal since the C standard library might (probably will) implement system-specific caching to unite smaller physical writes into larger physical writes, making your 20k writes per second more optimal.

Calling `fopen`/`fwrite`/`fclose` as you suggested, or `fflush` as EvilTeach suggested would elude that caching, which will probably degrade performance.